# How to reuse google cloud endpoints in multiple projects in android studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new in google cloud endpoints. I had successfully created some endpoints. Now I want to use APIs from these endpoints in other projects. For that, I will be needing APIs classes. Is there any way to compile my backend in other projects and get the API classes in other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need clients for your API. You can use [the Google Endpoints documentation to generate Java clients](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/gen_clients), or you can use the OpenAPI spec from your API to generate clients with a tool like [swagger-codegen](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/).